# Easiest way to setup custom NavigationBar in Swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

What is the easiest way to setup a custom NavigationBar in iOS/Swift?
I want to use a label above the navigation buttons (increased height). Is the only way to replace and hide the default NavigationBar and use an UIView?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(There's some missing things in your question, so this may not answer it.)

A `UINavigationBar` is simply a subclass of `UIView`, just as a `UINavigationController` is a subclass of a `UIViewController`. Where the former is just a "view" with a title and left/right bar buttons, the latter will have that and can also "control" a UIViewController stack.

Here's code for the former.

First, let's declare a label for the user name and a navigation bar with no title and a single left/right bar button. You can have an array of bar buttons on the left/right if you want. Also, I like to have SF Symbols with descriptive text, so I'll make UIButtons first.

```
let userName = UILabel()
let navBar = UINavigationBar()
let navItems = UINavigationItem(title: "")
var btnLeft:UIButton()
var btnRight:UIButton()
var barBtnLeft:UIBarButtonItem!
var barBtnRight:UIBarButtonItem!
```

Now let's populate things and set things up for auto layout. This all can be done during `viewDidLoad`, and change things (like user name) in other places.

```
// user name label

userName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
userName.text = "User Name"
userName.textAlignment = .center

// create UIButtons with an SF Symbol and description

btnLeft.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
btnLeft.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "lessthan"), for: .normal)
btnLeft.setTitle("  left", for: .normal)
btnLeft.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
btnRight.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
btnRight.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "greaterthan"), for: .normal)
btnRight.setTitle("  right", for: .normal)
btnRight.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)

// I like to "frame" these buttons, this is optional

btnLeft.layer.borderWidth = 1
btnLeft.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
btnLeft.layer.cornerRadius = 5
btnRight.layer.borderWidth = 1
btnRight.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
btnRight.layer.cornerRadius = 5

// now give the buttons a size

btnLeft.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
btnLeft.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
btnRight.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
btnRight.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

// don't forget to add targets!

btnLeft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(leftButtonSelector), for: .touchUpInside)
btnRight.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightButtonSelector), for: .touchUpInside)

// make the result be a bar button

barBtnLeft = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLeft)
barBtnRight = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnRight)

// add them to the navigation bar

navItems.leftBarButtonItems = [barBtnLeft]
navItems.rightBarButtonItems = [barBtnRight]
navBar.setItems([navItems], animated: false)
navBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// add the label and navigation bar to your view

view.addSubview(userName)
view.addSubview(navBar)

// finally, lay the user name above the navigation bar

userName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
userName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
userName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
userName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
navBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userName.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
navBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
navBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks, this way I would add it to the view controller's view. I guess it's not recommended to subclass UINavigationBar, cannot really find any good examples?

Comment: I'm not sure about what is recommended - my needs didn't require such a thing. I just wanted to use a combination UINavigationBar and UITable View as a coordinated subview in a single screen, with an "Add", "Edit", "Cancel", and "Done" in the navigation bar (deletes are part of the table view). If you can picture my UI, a navigation bar gives me everything I needed out of the box. What's the reason to subclass on your end?

Comment: I was looking for a "quick fix" and maybe use something like let navController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: CustomNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil) to replace the existing navigation bar initialized in AppDelegate. But it may be an even better idea to put the navigation bar in the base vieWController with your solution.